# Examples of categorized option within a dropdown?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for websites to use as an example that use categorized options within a drop down.

These may look like:

**Fruit**

- Apple
- Pear
- Peach
- Melon

**Vegetables**

- Asparagus
- Beetroot
- Broccoli

**Herbs**

- Basil
- Dill
- Ginger

The headings wouldn't be clickable, only the child options would be.

I'm sure I have seen websites do this before, but I'm struggling to find a good example.

Does anyone know of any websites that have adopted this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple dropdown with categorization.

```html
<select>
    <optgroup label="Fruit">
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
      <option value="pear">Pear</option>
      <option value="peach">Peach</option>
      <option value="melon">Melon</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Vegetables">
      <option value="asparagus">Asparagus</option>
      <option value="beetroot">Beetroot</option>
      <option value="broccoli">Broccoli</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Herbs">
      <option value="basil">Basil</option>
      <option value="dill">Dill</option>
      <option value="ginger">Ginger</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: that´s the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap's navbar with dropdown to reach this job:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

in the snippet you only will see the "smartphone version" due to width of snipet window, copy the code and test it by yourself in a full page.
Parent elements are clickable only to drop down child elements, and child elements are clickable to go somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as pure HTML and even through jQuery.

For HTML bellow is the snippet

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="pear">Pear</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="melon">Melon</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Vegetables">
    <option value="asparagus">Asparagus</option>
    <option value="beetroot">Beetroot</option>
    <option value="broccoli">Broccoli</option>
   </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Herbs">
    <option value="basil">Basil</option>
    <option value="dill">Dill</option>
    <option value="ginger">Ginger</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

and for jQuery bellow is snippet

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <a id="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown</a>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none;">
    <h3>Fruit</h3>
 <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Peach</li>
    <li>Melon</li>
 </ul>
 <h3>Vegetables</h3>
 <ul>
    <li>Asparagus</li>
    <li>Beetroot</li>
    <li>Broccoli</li>
 </ul>

 <h3>Herbs</h3>
 <ul>
    <li>Basil</li>
    <li>Dill</li>
    <li>Ginger</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

and here is it jQuery

```
<script>
 $('#dropdown').click(function(event) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
 });
</script>
```